# I need a sed command to change a phone number format from 999-999-9999 to (999)999-9999

Tags: unix, sed

I need a sed command to change a phone number format from `999-999-9999` to `(999)999-9999`.
Here is what I've been trying:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\-[[:digit:]]\-[[:digit:]]/\([[:digit:]]\)[[:digit:]]\-[[:digit:]]/gp'
```

I've also tried this:

```
sed 's/([0-9]{3})\-([0-9]{3})\-([0-9]{4})/\(([0-9]{3}\))([0-9]{3})\-([0-9]{4})/gp'
```

Comment: The `[[:digit:]]` units match a single digit, not triple digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation `[[:digit:]]` matches a single digit; you need to match repeated digits, which you do by wrapping the repeat count in `\{3\}` (for a fixed count; there are variable counted ranges too, but they're not relevant here, and `*` and so on too).  And you need to capture what you match in `\(…\)` so you can reference them in the replacement.  In the replacement, you use `\1` etc to refer to captured fragments.  The captures are numbered left-to-right in the order of the `\(` symbols.

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)-\([[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/(\1)\2/g'
```

Or:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)-\([0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)/(\1)\2/g'
```

This is classic `sed` notation; you can find variants using extended regular expressions too, but you need different options depending on platform, unlike this notation.  The patterns look for 3 digits (first capture), a dash, then 3 more digits, another dash and 4 digits as the second capture, and replace all that with open bracket (parenthesis in American), the first 3 digits, close bracket, and the remaining 3 digits, dash, 4 digits.

BSD (Mac OS X):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})/(\1)\2/g'
```

GNU:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})/(\1)\2/g'
```

Note that all of these regular expressions would convert

```
9876-345-54321
```

to:

```
9(876)345-54321
```

Fixing that is less trivial, especially in `sed`.  Using Perl:

```
$ echo "987-654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and 222-333-4444 and 543-432-5544" |
> perl -p -e 's/\b([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})\b/(\1)\2/g'
(987)654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and (222)333-4444 and (543)432-5544
$
```

The `\b` marks a word boundary in PCRE.  That does mean that `a222-333-4444` is not matched by the Perl; you can refine things to insist on non-digit or start of string before, and non-digit or end of string after, the matching string.

```
$ echo "987-654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and a222-333-4444 and 543-432-5544" |
> perl -p -e 's/(^|\D)([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})(\D|$)/\1(\2)\3\4/g' 
(987)654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and a(222)333-4444 and (543)432-5544
$
```

Or with (BSD or GNU) `sed` extended regular expressions (BSD shown):

```
$ echo "987-654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and a222-333-4444 and 543-432-5544" |
> sed -E 's/(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})([^0-9]|$)/\1(\2)\3\4/g'
(987)654-3210 and 2987-654-543210 and a(222)333-4444 and (543)432-5544
$
```

Note that the negated digit character class notation can be written `[^[:digit:]]` if you wish.

Iterative development helps.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!! Can you explain what exactly this part is doing, (\1)\2/  ?

Comment: In the first variant, `\(…\)` 'captures' a part of what's matched. In the replacement, you can refer to those captured fragments as often as needed (here, once each) using `\1` etc to refer to the fragments. The fragments are indexed by the sequence in which the `\(` symbols appear. So, the `(\1)\2` replaces the digit-dash string with an open bracket, the first 3-digit group, a close bracket and the second captured string (the 999-9999).

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 123-456-7890 | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})/(\1)\2/'
(123)456-7890
```

Comment: Why not using `awk`?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Because the question asks about `sed` (by the tag, and by illustrating what has been tried).  I don't see `awk` providing a big advantage here; using `gsub` or equivalent is feasible, but if anything the notation is clumsier than `sed`.

Comment: I think it was a joke.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, it was indeed a joke :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: sorry I missed the chuckle at the end of the question.